# Asyncore dispatcher blocking the whole app while sending large (stream) of data

Tags: python, multithreading, proxy, stream, asyncore

I am trying to make a script that will stream a live video stream through my server (a `.ts` stream which never ends). Furthermore, this stream is going through another proxy that has access to the original video stream itself.

I managed to write some code that is working, it is able to get the stream from the original source, through the proxy and stream it to the client, however it only works for just one client at a time (just one stream can go through), the rest of the app or other requests just keep hanging and never finish, until the current user that is watching the stream closes it.

I am using asyncore dispatcher, I thought this was supposed to have threading/async implemented and that it should handle multiple users by itself, however I was wrong, or I messed something in my code badly (which is most likely the case).

As you can see from the code below, I used the sample client/server application from asyncore to start with:

```
class EchoHandler(threading.Thread, asyncore.dispatcher):

  def __init__(self, sock):
    self.channel_lock = threading.Lock()
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, sock)

  def handle_read(self):
    self.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    header = self.recv(300)
    header = str(header)
    url =  (header.split('\n', 1)[0])[5:-10]
    threading.Thread(target=self.send_stream(), args=(url, ))
    #self.send_stream(url)

    #if data:
        #self.send(data)

  def handle_close(self):
    self.s.close()
    print "Connection closed"
    self.close()

  def send_stream(self, url):
    CRLF = "\r\n"

    request = [
        "GET "+ url +" HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: X.X.X.X",
        "Connection: Close",
        "",
        "",
    ]

    # Connect to the server
    self.s = socket.socket()
    self.s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    self.s.connect(('X.X.X.X', 3128))

    # Send an HTTP request
    self.s.send(CRLF.join(request))

    # Get the response (in several parts, if necessary)
    response = ''
    buffer = self.s.recv(50)
    while buffer:
        self.send(buffer)
        buffer = self.s.recv(50)

    self.close()

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):

  def __init__(self, host, port):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    self.set_reuse_addr()
    self.bind((host, port))
    self.listen(50)

  def handle_accept(self):
    pair = self.accept()
    if pair is not None:
        sock, addr = pair
        print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
        EchoHandler(sock)

server = EchoServer('localhost', 5555)

asyncore.loop()
```

This is basically the whole code.

As you might also see, I have tried to do something with threading, but failed at it, as it doesn't work at all like that.

Comment: @byako: You need to be really careful with indentation when editing Python code.  I have attempted to fix up the clearly incorrect indentation changes, but I might have missed some.  Of course, the OP should take care to paste code correctly in the first place (select pasted block, ctrl-K).

Comment: You should take care not to block when in a handler.  Using nonblocking reads is only part of the solution -- you should make sure you don't get stuck in a loop inside a method, because that will block the caller.  A common arrangement is to add stuff to a buffer in the `handle_read` and mark the socket as writable so that `handle_write` gets called to write it out.  I found http://code.activestate.com/recipes/259148-simple-http-server-based-on-asyncoreasynchat/ and https://parijatmishra.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/writing-a-server-with-pythons-asyncore-module/ to be instructive.

Comment: With asyncore, you actually won't need to use threading, either -- the point of the framework is to handle what's currently pending in a single loop; but then you mustn't block that loop.

Comment: @tripleee I am not sure how to do that. As you can see, I am creating a new socket connection inside the handle_read (the function send_stream does that) passing all the data through that connection to the client. I don't mind that that part is stuck, this new connection as I said is a video stream, and bytes are constantly incoming and should just be forwarded to the client that requested that.

The EchoServer is instantiating these clients, however once one client is blocked inside, this EchoServer fails to accept new ones. The inside clients (EchoHandler-s) should be asynchronous or not?